# How to graceful restart centos 7 along with mysql?

Tags: mysql, centos7, mariadb

My system is centos 7.4 with Mariadb 5.5.

I always run `reboot` to restart server.As my database is `Mariadb MyISAM`,I am not sure whether `reboot` will cause database inconsistency,maybe lost data,even database corrupt.

Is there a safe way(without any data lost) to restart server?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Why do you ever need to restart the server?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A `reboot` is an ordered shut down, so you won't have any problems at all as everything, including the MariaDB service is sent a stop signal and given a chance to stop before the OS restarts.